# wiring a bathroom exhaust fan to a continuous circuit

Tags: wiring, bathroom, exhaust

We are adding a bathroom fan to our bathroom that never had one. 
We found power from the attic that we may be able to use. 
This power joins the hallway ceiling light to the hallway switch. 
We would be using a 2 pole switch (top switch for vanity light and bottom switch for exhaust fan).
Is it possible to take power from that attic power? If so how and would we need 12/3 wire.

Comment: Are you the same person who asked [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/188847)?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It looks like you now have two separate accounts; you should [request that they be merged](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).